# laravel 5 Middleware giving unexpected output

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.1

In my laravel project I have a Middleware to check user role.

Now in routes.php I have 2 groups, one of them is admin area group, I have applied middleware to only that group.

It works till now as expected, if logged in user has admin rights then he can access admin pages.

But I am not even able to access other routes, they all are giving me unauthorised error. Even if I haven't applied middleware to those routes.

Means that CheckRole middleware is running globally on every request.

Others routes that are not admin area, those are accessed via angularjs.

Maybe I don't know how Middlewares actually works, and I am missing something. Please share your knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the role middleware to the `$middleware` array or the `$routeMiddleware` array? `$middleware` is global

Maybe update your post with some examples of your code. Specifically your `routes.php`, `kernel.php` and your `CheckRole.php`

Comment: I think I got it, I was adding my middleware to both $middleware and $routeMIddleware. I think $middleware array is for global middleware calls. Please tell me that's right theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding my middleware to both $middleware and $routeMiddleware. I think $middleware array is for global middleware calls.

I removed it from $middleware and it works great now.

This was simple.

Thanks to all, have nice day.